# Spring Boot 2 + Websockets + Load balancer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket, spring-rabbit

We have written simple message sending mechanism to client (logged in user based) from server by using spring boot + websocket.
Currently its running in a single server, which is working fine.
But our production servers running under load balancing environment.
How could we achieve where the messages are pushed from server nodes send to appropriate users.
Please advice the possibilities, I have read some articles about RabbitMQ with socketjs , but not clear will it work for load balancing.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple instances of your websocket server, then every instance needs to know the sessions that exists on other instances.

Therefore you need to use a broker relay (not the in-memory broker given by spring) and set the `UserRegistryBroadcast` property.

You can find some info related to this at the end of this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxakp15CACY